# How to pull a text from a table but the table has the same name as other tables? VBA, excel

Tags: excel, vba, datatable

I've made a code that would go to a website and pull their investment criteria. But I only need one cell in that table and the table class name is the same for multiple tables.

I need to get the EBITDA, which is on the table class = cTblListBody
Here's my code thus far:

```
 Sub SearchBot()

 Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
 Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 
 Dim y As Integer 
 Dim result As String 
 Dim TR As Object, TD As Object
 Dim tbl As Object, obj_tbl As Object

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer   
objIE.Visible = True 

objIE.navigate "https://website.com" 

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

objIE.document.getElementById("SearchTopBar").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value  
Set oNode = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("iPadHack tmbsearchright")  
(0) 
oNode.Click
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

b = 2  

Dim tblEle
Set tblEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody")(5)

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & b).Value = tblEle.innerText 
    Debug.Print tblEle.innerText

    b = b + 1
 Next     
objIE.Quit 'close the browser
```

End Sub

Full html code:

```
html
<head id="ctl02_headcontrol">
<body>
<div id="gcontainer" style="z-index:200000" onmouseout="calendarTimeout();"
onmouseover="if (timeoutId) clearTimeout(timeoutId);"></div>
<style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<img id="_jsVersionedShim" title=""
src="https://w3.ciqimg.com/CIQDOTNET/images/shim.gif?urwvid=3502569" alt=""
style="display:none;">
<script type="text/javascript">
<link title="IQ" rel="search"
type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"
href="/ciqdotnet/search/autocompleteprovidergenerator.axd">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="/CIQDOTNET/library/Combined/CIQHeader.css">
<style>
<div id="topBanner" style="width: 100%; height: 69px;">
<table style="height: 100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
border="0">
<tbody>
<tr valign="bottom">
<tr id="bodyrow" style="height:100%;" valign="top">
<td id="ll_leftBorder_mid">
<td id="ll_cont" class="ll_cont_ex">
<td id="leftPageBorder" style="width: 10px;">
<td style="width: 100%;">
<div id="contentArea">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="UpdateProgressDiv" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/CIQDotNet/Charting/Library/highstock.js">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/CIQDotNet/CreditAnalytics/CIQCharts/themes/light.js">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/CIQDotNet/CreditAnalytics/CIQCharts/lib/util.js">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/CIQDotNet/CreditAnalytics/CIQCharts/CIQCharts.js">
<style type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript"
src="/CIQDotNet/News/library/NewsAndBlogs.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
<form id="frmMain" method="post" action="./company.aspx?companyId=30995038">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/CIQDotNet/WebResource.axd?d=nZzj3YZngGCPUXbcooPdPCjPJSuAIp
DU_l-5lPsFAlauINflCZuBPW8NfeQFL1nsY13w4LY1&t=635802961220000000"
type="text/javascript">
<script language="javascript">
<script src="/CIQDotNet/LeftLinks/LeftLinksContent.aspx
 leftLinksHashKey=e1HX3w3nPsHpyHn6IEXdcA%3d%3d&urwvid=3502569"
 type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/CIQDotNet/library/CIQDotNet/Web/functional.js"
type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/CIQDotNet/ScriptResource.axd
d=BQRO1XhoYSDCQiunG6j3W6BEdFJUaLhgrsqvXzeFZkJH6K5tgvKMDrgFuDHlO
 1ymPMZRaduCK4dNstqE6toFrC4k8xUF9d5645" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/CIQDotNet/ScriptResource.axd?
<script src="Company/BubbleChart.asmx/js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/CIQDotNet/Research/Services/ResearchService.asmx/js"
type="text/javascript">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="CompanyHeaderInfo" class="cPageTitle" style="margin-bottom:38px;">
<table class="cTblListBody" style="width:100%;" border="1">
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:100%;">
<br class="tableSpacer">
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" cellspacing="0"
cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="cTblHeaderBG" style="width:100%;">
<table class="cTblListBody" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;"
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<a name="#ctl22$ctl09"></a>
<table class="cTblListBody" rules="all" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2"
bordercolor="#d8dde1" border="1">
<tbody>
<tr class="cColHeaderBG">
<tr>
<tr style="background-color:#F9F9F9;">
<tr>
<tr style="background-color:#F9F9F9;">
<td>EBITDA</td>
<td style="width:50px;" align="right">
<span></span>
-
</td>
<td style="width:50px;" align="right">
<td style="width:50px;" align="right">
<td style="width:50px;" align="right">
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="width:100%;">
<br class="tableSpacer">
<div> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script language="JavaScript">
<script language="JavaScript">
<script language="JavaScript">
<script type="text/javascript">
</form>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
</div>
</td>
<td id="rightPageBorder" style="width: 10px;">
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="btmFooter" class="ftrBG">
<a id="_hotkey1" accesskey="1" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(1);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(1)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey2" accesskey="2" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(2);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(2)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:1;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey3" accesskey="3" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(3);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(3)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:2;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey4" accesskey="4" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(4);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(4)" href="javascript:void(0);"\
style="position:fixed;top:3;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey5" accesskey="5" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(5);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(5)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:4;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey6" accesskey="6" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(6);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(6)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:5;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey7" accesskey="7" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(7);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(7)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:6;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey8" accesskey="8" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(8);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(8)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:7;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey9" accesskey="9" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(9);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(9)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:8;left:0"></a>
<a id="_hotkey0" accesskey="0" tabindex="-1" onclick="HotKey(0);"
onfocus="HotKeyIE(0)" href="javascript:void(0);"
style="position:fixed;top:9;left:0"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the *third* instance of that ClassName, so, instead of looping the collection of matching ClassName elements, try this:

```
Dim tblEle
Set tblEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody")(2)
```

Then, I think you can you get the cell value from that element.

Also note:

You use variable `i` but I don't see that declared anywhere in code: `For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody").Rows.
(i).Cells(1).innerText`.  Should this be `b` instead of `i`?

Comment: Okay so, I'm using the first code instead of the 

    For Each aEleInobjIE.document. getElementsByClassName
    ("cTblListBody").Rows.(i).Cells(1).innerText

I was looking at a friends code and was tricking to mimic the same procedure.

Comment: What would we define dim tblEle as then?

Comment: `Dim tblEle` is implicitly of Variant type, which can contain anything. You may want to do `Dim tblEle as Object` but that shouldn't matter.

Comment: I modified the code.  I need the 5th instance of the class name correct, not the 2nd.

Great now I need to loop the cells so that it will search cells A2: A1882. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @sameer please ask that as a separate question and avoid using the comments to ask a series of relayed follow ups  -- AFTER you research the topic. Looping is a fundamental programming concept.